# Parse JSON but preserve \n in strings

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON string:

```
{\"text\":\"Line 1\\nLine 2\",\"color\":\"black\"}
```

I can parse it when I do this:

```
pg = JSON.parse(myJSONString.replace(/\\/g, ""));
```

But when I access pg.text the value is:

```
Line 1nLine 2.
```

But I want the value to be exactly:

```
Line 1\nLine 2
```

The JSON string is valid in terms of the target program which interprets it as part of a larger command. It's Minecraft actually. Minecraft will render this as you would expect with Line 1 and Line 2 on separate lines.

But I'm making a editor that needs to read the \n back in as is. Which will be displayed in an html input field.

Just as some context here is the full command which contains some JSON code.

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{title‌​:"",author:"",pages:‌​["{\"text\":\"Line 1\\nLine 2\",\"color\":\"black\"}"]}},{}]}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by *"when I access pg.text"*? If it's in an `<input>` value, they do not support multi-line strings and all newlines are removed. You probably want a `<textarea>`

Comment: Why are the quotes escaped in your JSON? It seems like you have doubly-encoded it, so you need to parse it twice.

Comment: This is full command. This Minecraft NBT format. but is contains parts of JSON in the pages array: /summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{title:"",author:"",pages:["{\"text\":\"Line 1\\nLine 2\",\"color\":\"black\"}"]}},{}]}

Comment: @Andy, you don't have the same input string as OP: yours does not have all those backslashes as they are interpreted by the string literal notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding [1] at /\[1]/g but works for single slash only, but since the type of the quoted json i think is a string when you parse that it slash will automatically be removed so you don't even need to use replace. and \n will remain as.

```
      var myString ='{\"text\":\"Line 1\\nLine 2\",\"color\":\"black\"}';

      console.log(JSON.parse(myString.replace(/\\[1]/g, "")));    //adding [1] will remove single slash  \\n   -> \n

      var myString =JSON.parse(myString.replace(/\\[1]/g, ""));

      console.log(myString.text);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me but I did also have do this at the start: myString = "\""+jsonString+"\"";

Comment: This answer makes no sense: the `[1]` would require a literal 1 to occur in the string, and so the `replace` is not replacing anything. Secondly, the string that is used as input here does not have the backslashes before the double quotes, as they are interpreted by the string literal notation.

Comment: I don't really get the regex because I've not taken the time to learn it. But this code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not valid JSON, and ideally you should fix the code that generates it, or contact the provider of it.

If the issue is that there is always one backslash too many, then you could do this:

```js
// Need to escape the backslashes in this string literal to get the actual input:
var myJSONString = '{\\"text\\":\\"Line 1\\\\nLine 2\\",\\"color\\":\\"black\\"}';
console.log(myJSONString);

// Only replace backslashes that are not preceded by another:
var fixedJSON = myJSONString.replace(/([^\\])\\/g, "$1");
console.log(fixedJSON);

var pg = JSON.parse(fixedJSON);
console.log(pg);
```